# Firefox contextualIndetities (containers) on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, session, firefox, cookies, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to make a browser extension for Chrome which emulates Firefox containers? I know that SessionBox does that but I'm not sure how it works without using the contextual identities API

Comment: You would have to use webRequest API to intercept the `Cookie` and `Set-Cookie` headers. It's complicated.

Comment: Is it possible to use manifest V3 and the declarativeNetRequest API instead?

Comment: No, its predefined rules are too simple to define such a complex thing.